# Angular Material Select (mat-select) - How to set default value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

A lot of questions are discussing the way to set a default value to show in a "Select" control, here I am exposing an Angular 8 template driven forms case, where I cannot get the default value showing in the mat-select when the button is clicked, even if console.log shows the correct value:

```
<mat-select [formControl]="itemControl" required [(value)]="itemValue">
    <mat-option>--</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">{{item}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

My component code part is as follows:

```
export class MyComponent {

  items: string[] = [''];
  itemControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  itemValue: string = '';

  myButtonClick(): void {
        this.itemValue = this.getItems()[0];     <--- This returns the first element in a valid array
        console.log(this.itemValue);
      }
}
```

So what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using form control, you should assign the default value to itemControl, for example

```
  this.itemControl.patchValue(this.getItems()[0])
```

You can assign it from the onInit lifecycle hook or from the api response. So the form control can update the value accordingly. mat-select directive don't support two way data binding for value property.

Comment: can you please answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60465057/angular-rxjs-getting-subscriber-instead-of-the-required-value

Answer (score 0):

Example:

html:

```
 <form [formGroup]="entregaSelecao">
       <mat-form-field class="form-input">
           <mat-label>Bairro</mat-label>
           <mat-select disableRipple formControlName="bairro">
              <mat-option  *ngFor="let item of bairros" [value]="item">{{item}}</mat-option>
           </mat-select>
       </mat-form-field>
   </form>
```

.ts:

```
public enderecoForm: FormGroup;

bairros: string[] = ['bairro 1', 'bairro 2', 'bairro 3'];
ngOnInit() {
    this.entregaSelecao = this.formBuilder.group({
          entregaSelecionado: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}
```